# click on button -> display marker on map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've wrote a little javascript and html code for a project.
I want a new function in javascript, but I won't get any further.
I have a map API with markers and I have a table with images and adresses.
Now when I click the image I want the place to be shown on the map.
Here's my piece of code:

```
<table>
       <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Rijn IJssel Locaties</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td><img id="action" type="button" value="Show map" class="locatiepic" 
                 src="images/rijnijssel.jpg">
                <br> Rijn IJssel - Zijpendaalseweg 167</td>
            <td><img class="locatiepic"
                 src="images/Rijn%20IJssel%20locatie%20Alexanderstraat.png">
                <br> Rijn IJssel - Alexanderstraat 35</td>
            <td><img class="locatiepic" src="images/Rijn%20IJssel%20-
                %20Apeldoornseweg%20210a.jpg">
                <br> <p> Rijn IJssel - Apeldoornseweg 210a</p> </td>
      </tr>
<table>
```

And below the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
  ['Rijn IJssel - Zijpendaalseweg 167', 51.996098, 5.891174, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Alexanderstraat 35', 51.9847458, 5.8808427, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Apeldoornseweg 210a', 51.990575, 5.908738, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Beukenlaan 3', 52.0043576, 5.9268341, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Korianderstraat 81', 51.9671908, 5.9189638, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Utrechtsestraat 40/42', 51.984172, 5.897613, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Veluwestraat 120', 51.989220, 5.887532, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Kronenburgsingel 16', 51.960555, 5.899545, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Kamillelaan 8-10-12', 51.9658918, 5.9180286, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Middachtensingle 2', 51.984267, 5.956816, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Velperweg 39', 51.9875672, 5.9263741, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Papendallaan 51', 52.0108996, 5.8156799, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Thorbeckestraat 6', 51.981106, 5.926297, 'Arnhem'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Nijverheidsstraat 67a', 51.908003, 5.925714, 'Bemmel'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Tellegenlaan 2', 52.051328, 6.099109, 'Dieren'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Pr. Irenestraat 49', 51.920011, 5.846170, 'Elst'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Groeneweg 14', 51.9746782, 5.7347855, 'Renkum'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Hutteweg 24', 51.895614, 6.382502, 'Ulft'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Marijkeweg 5', 51.9692226, 5.6524946, 'Wageningen'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Marijkeweg 20', 51.9694141, 5.6540805, 'Wageningen'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Babberichseweg 23', 51.927324, 6.081011, 'Zevenaar'],
  ['Rijn IJssel - Stationsplein 8', 51.923190, 6.074446, 'Zevenaar'],
];

// Maps verbinden aan id "maps"
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    // Maps zoom afstand level 16
    zoom: 16,
    // Begin locatie
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.996098, 5.891174),
    // Map stijl
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.map
});

// info vakje bij klikken op locatie marker
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

// Markers plaatsen
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}



function clickroute(lati, long) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, long);
    map.panTo(latLng);
}
```

I've tried several things, but I can't get trough it.

Comment: You want to click on an Image within the Table and then display it on the Map? If yes, I don´t see any Table-Click-Event?

Comment: You have some HTML with placenames and images, and you have an array with placenames.  I'd suggest moving the image filenames into the array, use javascript to output the HTML using the placenames and images, and have an event listener on the `<td>` that knows which row in the array you're clicking on.